# Text shadow in TCPDF

Tags: php, tcpdf

We want to add text shadow in some text and not add text shadow in some text.
Is that possible using tcpdf

We want show price with text shadow and other content without text shadow

We are using this code for text shadow

```
$pdf->setTextShadow(array('enabled'=>true, 'depth_w'=>1, 'depth_h'=>1, 'color'=>array(255,0,0), 'opacity'=>1, 'blend_mode'=>'Normal'));
```

But its work for whole page

Answer (score 2):

After writing some text, you can then disable.

```
//Enable
$pdf->setTextShadow(array('enabled'=>true, 'depth_w'=>1, 'depth_h'=>1, 'color'=>array(255,0,0), 'opacity'=>1, 'blend_mode'=>'Normal'));
$pdf->MultiCell(60, '', 'some shadowed text', 0, 'L', false, 1, 85, 10);

//Disable
$pdf->setTextShadow(array('enabled'=>false, 'depth_w'=>1, 'depth_h'=>1, 'color'=>array(255,0,0), 'opacity'=>1, 'blend_mode'=>'Normal'));
$pdf->MultiCell(60, '', 'without shadowed text', 0, 'L', false, 1, 85, 25);
```